# My program crashes and I don't know why

Tags: java, android, crash

I'm learning how to program in Java for Android and my program keeps crashing.   It's suppoesed to convert from Celsius to Fahrenheit.

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener 
{

public static final int MY_CODE=2;
EditText temp;
RadioButton converttoF,converttoC,selectedtype;
RadioGroup conversion;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    conversion = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.conversion);
    conversion.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    converttoF = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.converttoF);
    converttoC = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.converttoC);




}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
{
    selectedtype = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);

    Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity4Result.class);
    i.putExtra("temper", temp.getText().toString());

    if(selectedtype.equals(converttoC))
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"C chosen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        i.putExtra("type", 'c');
        startActivityForResult(i, MY_CODE);
    }

    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"F chosen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        i.putExtra("type", 'f');
        startActivityForResult(i, MY_CODE);
    }       
  }       
}
```

My guess is that the problem is happening in the "onCheckedChanged", because it crashes when I push any RadioButton.

Comment: If your code throws an exception or if the compiler shows you an error message, then you'll want to post all the complete messages here with your question so we can see them.

Comment: Why is type of `checkedId` integer?

Comment: could you exdplain to me how do i send those messegas?

and as for the checkedId, i didnt know wxactly how to do it and my teacher said that the way its suppesed to be, is it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume (*It would be better if you post the crash log along with your question, so that we can help you better and stop assuming*) you are getting a *null pointer exception* on the following code:

```
i.putExtra("temper", temp.getText().toString());
```

In your code you declared `temp`, but it is never initialised. You need to initialise temp before using it.

Comment: i didnt initialised it because its an edit text, the app's user is supped to enter it's value.. am i right?

Comment: @AsafTavor: You need to find the edit text to the one you added to interface. like `temp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditTextId)`